# Knockout class binding not working in a component

Tags: html, css, knockout.js, font-awesome

I have created a knockout component and inside I am trying to bind a `span` element to a CSS class defined in a viewmodel. I normally used a `class` binding for this:

```
<span data-bind="class: IconCssClass"></span>
```

But for some reason, it does not work - it does not apply the class at all.
However, when I use a `css` binding or `attr` binding, both work as expected:

```
<span data-bind="attr: { 'class': IconCssClass }"></span>
<span data-bind="css: IconCssClass"></span>
```

Is it a knockout bug or am I missing something? Tried to google this out but it seems no-one else had encountered this issue.

Here's a code snippet:

```js
// Register a simple component:
ko.components.register('my-icon', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.IconCssClass = ko.computed(function () {
      return "fas fa-edit"; // hardcoded to keep the example simple
    }, this)
  },
  template: 'attr binding: <span data-bind="attr: { \'class\': IconCssClass }"></span> <br /> css binding: <span data-bind="css: IconCssClass"></span> <br /> class binding: <span data-bind="class: IconCssClass"></span>'
});

// Apply bindings
ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p>
    The component:
  </p>
  <my-icon></my-icon>

</body>
```

Comment: That's super weird... When I look for the class binding in `ko.bindingHandlers` it seems to be completely missing. Upgrading to knockout 3.5.0 does seem to fix it though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the reason so will answer my own question.

The `class` binding is new in knockout, it did not appear until knockout 3.5.0-beta.
This is unfortunately not mentioned in knockout documentation where `css` and `class` bindings are described together with no information that one of them is pretty new:
https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

You must look into release notes to find this info:

> The new `class` binding supports dynamic class strings. This allows you to use the `css` and `class` bindings together to support both methods of setting CSS classes.

Full knockout 3.5.0-beta release notes:
https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/tag/v3.5.0-beta

Comment: Thanks - was banging my head. NOTE: Version 3.5.0 introduced some breaking changes - see https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/tag/v3.5.0-beta